# What are differences between C# Automapper.Map method?

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper

My **Entity** class :

```
{
  //The Id attribute is guid autogenerated 
  public Guid Id {get; set;}
  //Some attributes
}
```

My **Source** class :

```
{
  //No Id
  //Some attributes      
}
```

I have 2 following code snippets :

```
    entity =  _mapper.Map(source,entity);
    UpdateAsync(entity); 
//and   
    entity =  _mapper.Map<Entity>(source);
    UpdateAsync(entity);
```

When i'm using the **first snippet**, the program run **successfully**.

But when i'm using the **another**, the compiler stopped and **throw the exception** :

"**Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.**"

... at the '**UpdateAsync**' method line.

**Note** : I'm debugging the program and i'm figure out that in the second way, attribute **Id** of the '**entity**' variable is generated **new guid**, wheraeas the first way is not

So, **What is the differences of 2 above snippets ?**

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Its hard to approach this question. Have you looked up the documentation on these to methods? Have you looked at the difference in the code inspector? the database is irrelevant to all this, you are mixing apples and oranges.

Comment: Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Comment: @TheGeneral can you explain more detailed for me ? 'You are mixing apples and oranges' - what do you mean ?. And can you point out what i'm missing ?